# Geolocator.PositionChanged event gets raises when I try GeoLocator.GetPositionAsync()

Tags: c#, xaml, geolocation, bing-maps

So, I'm getting some weird behavior when getting the current position using the GetPositionAsync method in my app. It seems to be firing the PositionChanged event when I query for the position. I'm not sure exactly what's going on and it's hard to debug since the call is asynchronous. Here's some sample code that illustrates the problem, (you'll need a Bing Maps key to test it):

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using Bing.Maps;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using GeoPositionExercise.Model;

namespace GeoPositionExercise
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage
    {
        private Geolocator _geolocator;
        private LocationIcon _locationIcon = new LocationIcon();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyMap.Children.Add(_locationIcon);
            _geolocator = new Geolocator();

            //LoadPoly(PolyLayer, DefaultStyle, GetLocation);
            _geolocator.PositionChanged += this._geolocator_PositionChanged;

        }

        private void _geolocator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, new DispatchedHandler(
                () =>
                {
                    displayPosition(this, args.Position.Coordinate);
                }));
        }

        private void displayPosition(object sender, Geocoordinate coordinate)
        {
            Location location = new Location(coordinate.Latitude, coordinate.Longitude);

            MapLayer.SetPosition(_locationIcon, location);
            MyMap.SetView(location, 15.0f);
        } 

        private async void GetLocation(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // This raises a PositionChanged event for some reason
            var position = await _geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<common:PageBase xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                 xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
                 xmlns:common="using:GeoPositionExercise.Common"
                 xmlns:local="using:GeoPositionExercise"
                 xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
                 x:Name="PageRoot"
                 x:Class="GeoPositionExercise.MainPage"
                 xmlns:m="using:Bing.Maps"
                 mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
                 DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <AppBar>
            <AppBarButton Label="Get Location" Tapped="GetLocation">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE118;" />
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
        </AppBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>

    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,0,0,53">
        <m:Map x:Name="MyMap" Credentials="YOUR BING MAP KEY HERE" >
            <m:MapLayer x:Name="PinLayer"/>
            <m:MapLayer x:Name="InfoboxLayer" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Grid x:Name="Infobox" Width="350">
                    <Border Background="Black" Opacity="0.8" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5"/>
                    <Grid Margin="5">
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="InfoboxTitle" FontSize="18" Width="290" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            <WebView x:Name="InfoboxDescription" Width="330" Height="100" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </m:MapLayer>
        </m:Map>
    </Grid>
</common:PageBase>
```

And finally a user control LocationIcon:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="GeoPositionExercise.Model.LocationIcon"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:GeoPositionExercise.Model"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Canvas>
        <Ellipse Height="25" Width="25" Fill="#FFF0F0F0" Margin="-12.5,-12.5,0,0"></Ellipse>
        <Ellipse Height="20" Width="20" Fill="Black" Margin="-10,-10,0,0"></Ellipse>
        <Ellipse Height="10" Width="10" Fill="White" Margin="-5,-5,0,0"></Ellipse>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Make sure to have the right references and target a X64 or x82 platform before compiling. You can test this by clicking the "Get Location" app bar button, it'll always center the map at the current location. I'm not really sure why this is occuring, since the only place I call displayPosition is in the _geolocator_PostionChanged method.

Comment: A work around could be to check the MapLayer 's current Location before using SetPosition to update with the same location.

Also, may be you want to check out StatusChanged event for the same.

Comment: It does not raise the event "for some reason". The call to this method is supposed to raise the PositionChanged event, since a new position is calculated. In what case does that create a problem for you ?

Comment: Your `_geolocator_PositionChanged` method is called (repeatedly) simply because you've added it to the `PositionChanged` event. That's how Geolocator works. Adding the handler starts position updates. You don't need any additional `GetGeopositionAsync`. Just use the last position provided by `PositionChanged`.

Comment: For a working example see the `PhoneApplication` sample app in [XAML Map Control](http://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I didn't realize that the GetGeopositionAsync was supposed to call the PositionChanged event and didn't see it any documentation. But, I was thinking about it the wrong way. I can save the current position when PositionChanged is called and use that throughout my app instead of querying for it when I need it. Thanks.

Comment: Actually it is *not* GetGeopositionAsync that makes the PositionChanged being called. It is simply that you've attached a handler for that event.